# Click Button in iframe in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, iframe, webbrowser-control

I'm using C#, win apps, trying to click a button that found in a iframe on my webbrowser.

HTML:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="EditorIFrmae" name="EditorIFrmae" width="100%" height="700" style="z-index: 0; height: 852px;" src="X"></iframe>
```

In the iframe code:

```
<div height="" width="100%" style="position: relative; min-height: 50px;" onclick="javascript:funcEditPage('SB_Content_Page','SB_Content_PagePreview','PAGE5.asp');" class="SB_DivContentPreview" id="SB_Content_PagePreview">
</div>
```

My code:

```
HtmlElementCollection linkit = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement foundit in linkit)
            {
                if (foundit.GetAttribute("id").Equals("SB_Content_PagePreview"))
                {
                    foundit.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
```

How am I able to click on the button?

Comment: very unclear question. what's the problem be more specific

Comment: @FarhanAnam - I'm sry it wasn't clear enough:
Im trying to click a div that found in ifame and not on the curret page.

Comment: Your code looks fine what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @FarhanAnam - The problem, by my guess is that my code cant find the div cause he is in the iframe page and not on the curret page. The error that I get is like - div not found

Comment: Oh so the button is not clicked. this fact you mention nowhere in your question. Whatever, returning to the problem, you should use HTML Agility Pack instead of the WebBrowser if you don't need the page to be displayed.

Comment: and why do you use <something>.Equals(<another thing>) instead of <something> = <another thing>?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a frame using `Document.Window.Frames[]` that accepts id(string) or index(int) of frame.

Also you should consider you should wait until `DocumentCompleted` event raise and then do your job. When there are some iframe in a page, `DocumentCompleted` event fires more than once and using below code by checking the url of eventarg we make sure that this is the `DocumentCompleted` event of main page that we need, then you can enable a flag to say the document is completed and here or somewhere else, find the frame and the element you want.

Where is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(@"d:\test.html");
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    bool completed = false;
    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url == webBrowser1.Document.Url)
        {
            completed = true;
        }
    }

    private void clickToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(completed)
        {
            var frame = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["iframeid"];
            var button = frame.Document.GetElementById("buttonid");
            button.InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```

**Content of test.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>OUTER</title>
</head>
<body>
    Some Content <br/>
    Some Content <br/>
    Some Content <br/>
    iframe:
    <iframe src="test2.html" id="iframeid"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Content of test2.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>IFRAME</title>
</head>
<body>
   <button id="buttonid" onclick="alert('Clicked')">Click Me</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for Document to be **completely loaded** before trying to find elements into it and as you load **a frame**, you must search **inside a frame** too.
**Subscribe to `DocumentCompleted` event**:

```
initialUrl = new Uri(/* your url */);
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += OnDocumentCompleted;
webBrowser.Navigate(initialUrl);
```

and then try to find elements inside the method:

```
    private void OnDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
       if (args.Url == initialUrl)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection elements =
                webBrowser.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("id").Equals("SB_Content_PagePreview"))
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for trying help me, but it dosen't help much.

Comment: Yes. I did miss the frame use.

Answer (score 0):

```
 HtmlElementCollection linkit = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe");
            foreach (HtmlElement foundit in linkit)
            {
                if (foundit.GetAttribute("id").Equals("EditorIFrmae"))
                {
                    string iframeurl = foundit.GetAttribute("src");
                }
            }
```

Thats an option that i use to get the iframe link and then navigate to that link.